# Java kill suddenly

Tags: lucene, java

I am getting this error when  writer.optimize() called  I have caugh all  exceptions but hopeless .writer is an instance of apache lucene Indexwriter and tomcat collapse when optimizing the indexwriter.I am trying to index a large number of file its works for a few number of file but when number of files increase it cause to tomcat fail.

```
logger.info("Optimizing optimazing...");

            this.writer.optimize();

            logger.info("Optimizing closing...");

            this.writer.close();

            logger.info("Optimazide and  closed succesfully...");




#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fe6f8c38e90, pid=10316, tid=140629887768320
#
# JRE version: 6.0_20-b20
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (19.0-b09 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Derivative: IcedTea6 1.9.7
# Distribution: Ubuntu 10.10, package 6b20-1.9.7-0ubuntu1
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x54ae90]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-6/
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000000023e0000):  JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=10333, stack(0x00007fe6f2715000,0x00007fe6f2816000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x0000000000000008

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x00007fe6f2812930, RCX=0x00007fe6ec03e9e0, RDX=0x0000000000002000
RSP=0x00007fe6f2811150, RBP=0x00007fe6f2811190, RSI=0x00007fe6e43a20f0, RDI=0x0000000000000000
R8 =0x00007fe6e43f5a70, R9 =0x00007fe6f2812930, R10=0x00007fe6ec6f7948, R11=0x0000000000000000
R12=0x00007fe6edd326b0, R13=0x00007fe6ec6f7948, R14=0x00007fe6f2812950, R15=0x00007fe6ec068990
RIP=0x00007fe6f8c38e90, EFL=0x0000000000010206, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000
0x0000000000000000 is pointing to unknown location

RBX=0x00007fe6f2812930
0x00007fe6f2812930 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000023e0000
"CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00000000023e0000 nid=0x285d runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

RCX=0x00007fe6ec03e9e0
0x00007fe6ec03e9e0 is pointing to unknown location

RDX=0x0000000000002000
0x0000000000002000 is pointing to unknown location

RSP=0x00007fe6f2811150
0x00007fe6f2811150 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000023e0000
"CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00000000023e0000 nid=0x285d runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

RBP=0x00007fe6f2811190
0x00007fe6f2811190 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000023e0000
"CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00000000023e0000 nid=0x285d runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

RSI=0x00007fe6e43a20f0
0x00007fe6e43a20f0 is pointing to unknown location

RDI=0x0000000000000000
0x0000000000000000 is pointing to unknown location

R8 =0x00007fe6e43f5a70
0x00007fe6e43f5a70 is pointing to unknown location

R9 =0x00007fe6f2812930
0x00007fe6f2812930 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000023e0000
"CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00000000023e0000 nid=0x285d runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

R10=0x00007fe6ec6f7948
0x00007fe6ec6f7948 is pointing to unknown location

R11=0x0000000000000000
0x0000000000000000 is pointing to unknown location

R12=0x00007fe6edd326b0
0x00007fe6edd326b0 is pointing to unknown location

R13=0x00007fe6ec6f7948
0x00007fe6ec6f7948 is pointing to unknown location

R14=0x00007fe6f2812950
0x00007fe6f2812950 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000023e0000
"CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00000000023e0000 nid=0x285d runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

R15=0x00007fe6ec068990
0x00007fe6ec068990 is pointing to unknown location


Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007fe6f2811150)
0x00007fe6f2811150:   00007fe6e4522cd0 00007fe6f2811420
0x00007fe6f2811160:   00007fe6f2811190 00007fe6f2812930
0x00007fe6f2811170:   0000000000000002 00007fe6edd326b0
0x00007fe6f2811180:   00007fe6ec5d6430 00007fe6f2811420
0x00007fe6f2811190:   00007fe6f2811200 00007fe6f8c3941b
0x00007fe6f28111a0:   0000000000000002 00007fe600000100
0x00007fe6f28111b0:   00007fe600000001 00007fe6f28132d0
w-p 00021000 08:01 17301749                   /lib/ld-2.12.1.so
7fe6fa020000-7fe6fa021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fffd5558000-7fffd5579000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fffd55ff000-7fffd5600000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/murat/Desktop/servers/apache-tomcat-6.0.24/conf/logging.properties -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1|expertPC -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=11550,server=y,suspend=n -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/murat/Desktop/servers/apache-tomcat-6.0.24/endorsed -Dcatalina.base=/home/murat/Desktop/servers/apache-tomcat-6.0.24 -Dcatalina.home=/home/murat/Desktop/servers/apache-tomcat-6.0.24 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/murat/Desktop/servers/apache-tomcat-6.0.24/temp 
java_command: org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk
JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
USERNAME=murat
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/../lib/amd64
SHELL=/bin/bash
DISPLAY=:0.0

Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0x723630], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0x723630], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0x5e0000], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGPIPE: SIG_IGN, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0x5e0000], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0x5e0000], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGUSR2: [libjvm.so+0x5df710], sa_mask[0]=0x00000004, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGHUP: [libjvm.so+0x5e2180], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGINT: SIG_IGN, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGTERM: [libjvm.so+0x5e2180], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGQUIT: [libjvm.so+0x5e2180], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:Ubuntu 10.10 (maverick)
uname:Linux 2.6.35-28-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 18 18:42:20 UTC 2011 x86_64
libc:glibc 2.12.1 NPTL 2.12.1 
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k, NPROC infinity, NOFILE 1024, AS infinity
load average:0.77 0.30 0.14

/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:        4054828 kB
MemFree:          176928 kB
Buffers:          207640 kB
Cached:          1332820 kB
SwapCached:        17608 kB
Active:          2419624 kB
Inactive:        1004992 kB
Active(anon):    1834536 kB
Inactive(anon):    67792 kB
Active(file):     585088 kB
Inactive(file):   937200 kB
Unevictable:          16 kB
Mlocked:              16 kB
SwapTotal:      11876348 kB
SwapFree:       11687616 kB
Dirty:              3508 kB
Writeback:            32 kB
AnonPages:       1873148 kB
Mapped:           197036 kB
Shmem:             18240 kB
Slab:             157916 kB
SReclaimable:     131452 kB
SUnreclaim:        26464 kB
KernelStack:        3928 kB
PageTables:        32140 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    13903760 kB
Committed_AS:    3427468 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      323536 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359412360 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      272384 kB
DirectMap2M:     3919872 kB


CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 23 stepping 10, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1

Memory: 4k page, physical 4054828k(176928k free), swap 11876348k(11687616k free)

vm_info: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (19.0-b09) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.6.0_20-b20), built on Feb 23 2011 09:05:53 by "buildd" with gcc 4.4.5

time: Mon Jun  6 22:24:11 2011
elapsed time: 2076 seconds
```

Comment: looks like internal bug in the JVM, could be an issue w/ attaching a debugger and deoptimizing/optimizing? also, tomcat 6.24 is quite buggy on its own (not related to your case, though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Stéphane says, try different JREs to see if you can get a different error message.  There's a chance (but hard to quantify) that this is related to reaching a memory limit, but it'll be hard to be sure unless you do get an error saying which one!

Comment: memory issue seems a good target since the java args miss any memory specific options

Answer (score 0):

Use sun/oracle java jdk, not the open jdk...

Regards,
   Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

Since it is most likely a bug in the JVM, the first thing I would try is updating your JVM to Java 6 update 25.  You could try the Sun/Oracle JVM, but it likely to be the same.

I am assuming you are not using an JNI libraries?