# JVM crashes continuously during lucene indexing

Tags: java, lucene, jvm-crash

JVM crashes continuously. I can't to figure out what the problem is. I tested with the latest 1.6 jdk as well as 1.7. The same problem.

I have run the memory check and the no errors were reported. I also tried jrockit and the same thing happened there. The java code is an indexing process that adds documents to the Lucene index. It happens after some documents have been added to the index and committed.

JVM is started as with these options:

```
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -server -d64 -XX:MaxPermSize=1g -Xms4g -Xmx12g
```

The output from garbage collection log (notice the last line, seems like jvm is unable perform full gc): http://pastebin.com/9EskW4QY

The crash report looks like this:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f0db0736950, pid=11730, tid=139682413950736
#
# JRE version: 6.0_16-b01
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (14.2-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x548950]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f0a5404b800):  VMThread [stack: 0x00007f0a589a3000,0x00007f0a58aa4000] [id=11750]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=128 (), si_addr=0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x00007f0db0ab1090, RBX=0x00000000413d87d0, RCX=0x00000000413d87d0, RDX=0x0000000040a03c48
RSP=0x00007f0a58aa2698, RBP=0x00007f0a58aa26d0, RSI=0x79726f6dc5961e38, RDI=0x00007f0db0bcac20
R8 =0x00007f0db0a9b2d0, R9 =0x00007f0dac8e30d0, R10=0x0000000000000003, R11=0x00007f0dac8e6220
R12=0x00007f0a58c7aeb0, R13=0x00007f0a540011d0, R14=0x00007f0db0bcac20, R15=0x0000000000001bd4
RIP=0x00007f0db0736950, EFL=0x0000000000010246, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000000
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000d

Top of Stack: (sp=0x00007f0a58aa2698)
0x00007f0a58aa2698:   00007f0db054e3a8 00007f0a58aa2750
0x00007f0a58aa26a8:   00000000413b88d0 0000000000001ee2
0x00007f0a58aa26b8:   00007f0db0bcac20 00007f0a58aa2750
0x00007f0a58aa26c8:   0000000040116880 00007f0a58aa27f0
0x00007f0a58aa26d8:   00007f0db0530aa2 00007f0db0bcab40
0x00007f0a58aa26e8:   00007f0db0496d3e 00007f0a58aa2760
0x00007f0a58aa26f8:   00007f0a58aa2730 00007f0db0ab61f0
0x00007f0a58aa2708:   000000000521ed88 00007f0a58aa2790
0x00007f0a58aa2718:   00000001b052896f 0000000058aa2730
0x00007f0a58aa2728:   0000000000000000 00007f0a77ce82d0
0x00007f0a58aa2738:   00007f0a77ce82a8 00007f0a763b0000
0x00007f0a58aa2748:   000000005eb34000 0000000040010100
0x00007f0a58aa2758:   0000000000000000 00007f0a77ce82a8
0x00007f0a58aa2768:   00007f0a58aa2700 00007f0a58aa27b0
0x00007f0a58aa2778:   000000004010ba70 00007f0db0a86390
0x00007f0a58aa2788:   3ff0cccccccccccd 000000003f010100
0x00007f0a58aa2798:   0000000000000000 00007f0db0a86230
0x00007f0a58aa27a8:   0000000000000100 00007f0a58aa27f0
0x00007f0a58aa27b8:   000000004010ba70 3f6c3e5300000000
0x00007f0a58aa27c8:   0000000000000000 00000000401ef320
0x00007f0a58aa27d8:   00000000401ef420 0000000000000000
0x00007f0a58aa27e8:   00007f0a58aa2870 00007f0a58aa2900
0x00007f0a58aa27f8:   00007f0db048c880 00007f0a58aa2810
0x00007f0a58aa2808:   00000000b04b0741 00007f0a58aa28a0
0x00007f0a58aa2818:   0000000040116880 00007f0a58aa2850
0x00007f0a58aa2828:   00007fff939af637 00007f0db0aa1cb0
0x00007f0a58aa2838:   00007f0a58aa2880 00007f0a54048c60
0x00007f0a58aa2848:   00007fff939af800 00007f0a54048c60
0x00007f0a58aa2858:   00000000401ef8c0 00007f0a54048c60
0x00007f0a58aa2868:   0000000068000000 00007f0a54048c60
0x00007f0a58aa2878:   00007f0a763b0000 0000000066b34000
0x00007f0a58aa2888:   00007f0a5404a370 00007f0a6bd50000 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007f0db0736950)
0x00007f0db0736940:   e8 0b 5f d7 ff e8 56 8a 04 00 c9 c3 66 66 66 90
0x00007f0db0736950:   48 8b 16 55 48 89 e5 c9 83 e2 03 48 83 fa 03 0f 

Stack: [0x00007f0a589a3000,0x00007f0a58aa4000],  sp=0x00007f0a58aa2698,  free space=1021k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x548950]
V  [libjvm.so+0x342aa2]
V  [libjvm.so+0x29e880]
V  [libjvm.so+0x29e10a]
V  [libjvm.so+0x29de18]
V  [libjvm.so+0x33ff89]
V  [libjvm.so+0x3412c8]
V  [libjvm.so+0x6be4e0]
V  [libjvm.so+0x6cb14a]
V  [libjvm.so+0x6ca6f2]
V  [libjvm.so+0x6ca974]
V  [libjvm.so+0x6ca46e]
V  [libjvm.so+0x59726f]

VM_Operation (0x00007f0a581084c0): GenCollectForPermanentAllocation, mode: safepoint, requested by thread 0x00000000412c9800


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x00000000408fd800 JavaThread "Checkpointer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11779, stack(0x00007f0a53182000,0x00007f0a53283000)]
  0x00000000408fd000 JavaThread "Cleaner-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11778, stack(0x00007f0a53283000,0x00007f0a53384000)]
  0x000000004048a800 JavaThread "INCompressor" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11777, stack(0x00007f0a53384000,0x00007f0a53485000)]
  0x000000004087c800 JavaThread "Checkpointer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11776, stack(0x00007f0a53485000,0x00007f0a53586000)]
  0x0000000040991000 JavaThread "Cleaner-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11775, stack(0x00007f0a53586000,0x00007f0a53687000)]
  0x000000004095c800 JavaThread "INCompressor" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11774, stack(0x00007f0a53687000,0x00007f0a53788000)]
  0x0000000040869000 JavaThread "Checkpointer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11772, stack(0x00007f0a53788000,0x00007f0a53889000)]
 .....

Other Threads:
=>0x00007f0a5404b800 VMThread [stack: 0x00007f0a589a3000,0x00007f0a58aa4000] [id=11750]
  0x0000000040299000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x00007f0a5815c000,0x00007f0a5825d000] [id=11758]

VM state:at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x000000004010fd50] Threads_lock - owner thread: 0x00007f0a5404b800
[0x00000000401102d0] Heap_lock - owner thread: 0x00000000412c9800

Heap
 par new generation   total 153344K, used 58394K [0x00007f0a6bd50000, 0x00007f0a763b0000, 0x00007f0a763b0000)
  eden space 136320K,  40% used [0x00007f0a6bd50000, 0x00007f0a6f339d00, 0x00007f0a74270000)
  from space 17024K,  18% used [0x00007f0a74270000, 0x00007f0a7458ce00, 0x00007f0a75310000)
  to   space 17024K,   0% used [0x00007f0a75310000, 0x00007f0a75310000, 0x00007f0a763b0000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 4173056K, used 25696K [0x00007f0a763b0000, 0x00007f0b74ef0000, 0x00007f0d6bd50000)
 concurrent-mark-sweep perm gen total 58336K, used 55225K [0x00007f0d6bd50000, 0x00007f0d6f648000, 0x00007f0dabd50000)

Dynamic libraries:
40000000-40009000 r-xp 00000000 08:22 28821104                           /opt/java/jdk1.6.0_16/bin/java
40108000-4010a000 rwxp 00008000 08:22 28821104                           /opt/java/jdk1.6.0_16/bin/java
4010a000-41ed8000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f0a53182000-7f0a53185000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a53185000-7f0a53283000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a53283000-7f0a53286000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a53286000-7f0a53384000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a53384000-7f0a53387000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a53387000-7f0a53485000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a53485000-7f0a53488000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a53488000-7f0a53586000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a53586000-7f0a53589000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a53589000-7f0a53687000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a53687000-7f0a5368a000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a5368a000-7f0a53788000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a53788000-7f0a5378b000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a5378b000-7f0a53889000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a53889000-7f0a5388c000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a5388c000-7f0a5398a000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a5398a000-7f0a53990000 r-xp 00000000 08:22 28893265                   /opt/java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/amd64/libmanagement.so
7f0a53990000-7f0a53a8f000 ---p 00006000 08:22 28893265                   /opt/java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/amd64/libmanagement.so
7f0a53a8f000-7f0a53a91000 rwxp 00005000 08:22 28893265                   /opt/java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/amd64/libmanagement.so
7f0a53a91000-7f0a53aa9000 r-xs 0014e000 08:22 6512686                    /home/frank/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-core/3.5.0/lucene-core-3.5.0.jar
7f0a53aa9000-7f0a53aab000 r-xs 00009000 08:22 22701257                   /home/frank/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.2/commons-cli-1.2.jar
7f0a53aab000-7f0a53aae000 r-xs 00025000 08:22 25094196                   /home/frank/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.1/commons-io-2.1.jar
7f0a53aae000-7f0a53ab0000 r-xs 00007000 08:22 27115544                   /home/frank/.m2/repository/no/ntnu/idi/utils/nt-utils/1.0-SNAPSHOT/nt-utils-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
7f0a53ab0000-7f0a53ab9000 r-xs 0006d000 08:22 25102181                   /home/frank/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.16/log4j-1.2.16.jar
7f0a53ab9000-7f0a53abb000 r-xs 00005000 08:22 25094191                   /home/frank/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.6.4/slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar
7f0a53abb000-7f0a53abc000 r-xs 00002000 08:22 25094190                   /home/frank/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.6.4/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar
7f0a53abc000-7f0a53abf000 r-xs 00022000 08:22 24822053                   /home/frank/.m2/repository/org/jsoup/jsoup/1.5.2/jsoup-1.5.2.jar
7f0a53abf000-7f0a53ae0000 r-xs 0022c000 08:22 6504464                    /home/frank/.m2/repository/com/sleepycat/je/5.0.34/je-5.0.34.jar
7f0a53bd3000-7f0a53bd5000 r-xs 0000b000 08:22 25102201                   /home/frank/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-exec/1.1/commons-exec-1.1.jar
7f0a53bdf000-7f0a53be2000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a53be2000-7f0a53ce0000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a53ce0000-7f0a53ce3000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a53ce3000-7f0a53de1000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a53de1000-7f0a53de8000 r-xp 00000000 08:22 28893221                   /opt/java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/amd64/libnio.so
7f0a53de8000-7f0a53ee7000 ---p 00007000 08:22 28893221                   /opt/java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/amd64/libnio.so
7f0a53ee7000-7f0a53ee9000 rwxp 00006000 08:22 28893221                   /opt/java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/amd64/libnio.so
7f0a53ee9000-7f0a53efc000 r-xp 00000000 08:22 28893220                   /opt/java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so
7f0a53efc000-7f0a53ffd000 ---p 00013000 08:22 28893220                   /opt/java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so
7f0a53ffd000-7f0a54000000 rwxp 00014000 08:22 28893220                   /opt/java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so
7f0a54000000-7f0a5777f000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a5777f000-7f0a58000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a58001000-7f0a58005000 r-xs 00033000 08:22 22274907                   /home/frank/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/2.0.5/plexus-utils-2.0.5.jar
7f0a58005000-7f0a58007000 r-xs 00002000 08:22 22274904                   /home/frank/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interactivity-api/1.0-alpha-4/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-4.jar
7f0a58007000-7f0a58009000 r-xs 00006000 08:22 22274908                   /home/frank/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.0/commons-cli-1.0.jar
7f0a58009000-7f0a5800a000 r-xs 00001000 08:22 22274910                   /home/frank/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.0-alpha-7/doxia-sink-api-1.0-alpha-7.jar
7f0a5800a000-7f0a5800d000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a5800d000-7f0a5810b000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a5810b000-7f0a5810d000 r-xs 00005000 08:22 28287295                   /opt/maven/3.0.2/lib/wagon-http-shared-1.0-beta-7.jar
7f0a5810d000-7f0a5810e000 r-xs 00006000 08:22 28287299                   /opt/maven/3.0.2/lib/aether-connector-wagon-1.9.jar
7f0a5810e000-7f0a58113000 r-xs 00023000 08:22 28287283                   /opt/maven/3.0.2/lib/sisu-inject-bean-1.4.3.1.jar
7f0a58113000-7f0a58116000 r-xs 00019000 08:22 28287297                   /opt/maven/3.0.2/lib/nekohtml-1.9.6.2.jar
7f0a58116000-7f0a58118000 r-xs 00008000 08:22 28287296                   /opt/maven/3.0.2/lib/xercesMinimal-1.9.6.2.jar
7f0a58118000-7f0a5811b000 r-xs 0000a000 08:22 28287281                   /opt/maven/3.0.2/lib/maven-plugin-api-3.0.2.jar
7f0a5811b000-7f0a5811d000 r-xs 0000d000 08:22 28287274                   /opt/maven/3.0.2/lib/plexus-interpolation-1.14.jar
7f0a5811d000-7f0a58120000 r-xs 00011000 08:22 28287287                   /opt/maven/3.0.2/lib/aether-api-1.9.jar
7f0a58120000-7f0a58121000 r-xs 00006000 08:22 28287276                   /opt/maven/3.0.2/lib/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
7f0a58121000-7f0a58123000 r-xs 00002000 08:22 28287277                   /opt/maven/3.0.2/lib/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
7f0a58123000-7f0a58129000 r-xs 00040000 08:22 28287291                   /opt/maven/3.0.2/lib/maven-compat-3.0.2.jar
7f0a58129000-7f0a5812b000 r-xs 00000000 08:22 28287275                   /opt/maven/3.0.2/lib/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
7f0a5812b000-7f0a5812d000 r-xs 0000b000 08:22 28287292                   /opt/maven/3.0.2/lib/wagon-provider-api-1.0-beta-7.jar
7f0a5812d000-7f0a58130000 r-xs 00008000 08:22 28287273                   /opt/maven/3.0.2/lib/maven-settings-builder-3.0.2.jar
7f0a58130000-7f0a58132000 r-xs 0000b000 08:22 28287279                   /opt/maven/3.0.2/lib/maven-artifact-3.0.2.jar
7f0a58132000-7f0a58137000 r-xs 00020000 08:22 28287285                   /opt/maven/3.0.2/lib/maven-model-builder-3.0.2.jar
7f0a58137000-7f0a58138000 r-xs 00003000 08:22 28287294                   /opt/maven/3.0.2/lib/wagon-http-lightweight-1.0-beta-7.jar
7f0a58138000-7f0a5813a000 r-xs 00009000 08:22 28287293                   /opt/maven/3.0.2/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar
7f0a5813a000-7f0a5813d000 r-xs 0001a000 08:22 28287290                   /opt/maven/3.0.2/lib/aether-impl-1.9.jar
7f0a5813d000-7f0a5813f000 r-xs 00002000 08:22 28287288                   /opt/maven/3.0.2/lib/aether-spi-1.9.jar
7f0a5813f000-7f0a58140000 r-xs 0000a000 08:22 28287268                   /opt/maven/3.0.2/lib/maven-embedder-3.0.2.jar
7f0a58140000-7f0a58142000 r-xs 00006000 08:22 28287278                   /opt/maven/3.0.2/lib/maven-repository-metadata-3.0.2.jar
7f0a58142000-7f0a58144000 r-xs 0000a000 08:22 28287269                   /opt/maven/3.0.2/lib/maven-settings-3.0.2.jar
7f0a58144000-7f0a58147000 r-xs 00026000 08:22 28287272                   /opt/maven/3.0.2/lib/maven-model-3.0.2.jar
7f0a58147000-7f0a58149000 r-xs 0000c000 08:22 28287286                   /opt/maven/3.0.2/lib/maven-aether-provider-3.0.2.jar
7f0a58149000-7f0a5814a000 r-xs 00002000 08:22 28287298                   /opt/maven/3.0.2/lib/wagon-file-1.0-beta-7.jar
7f0a5814a000-7f0a58151000 r-xs 0002c000 08:22 28287282                   /opt/maven/3.0.2/lib/sisu-inject-plexus-1.4.3.1.jar
7f0a58151000-7f0a5815c000 r-xs 0006a000 08:22 28287284                   /opt/maven/3.0.2/lib/sisu-guice-2.9.1-noaop.jar
7f0a5815c000-7f0a5815d000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a5815d000-7f0a5825d000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a5825d000-7f0a58260000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a58260000-7f0a5835e000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a5835e000-7f0a58361000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a58361000-7f0a5845f000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a5845f000-7f0a58462000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a58462000-7f0a58560000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a58560000-7f0a58563000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a58563000-7f0a58661000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a58661000-7f0a58664000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a58664000-7f0a58762000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a58762000-7f0a587a1000 r-xp 00000000 08:22 23102913                   /usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_CTYPE
7f0a587a1000-7f0a587a4000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a587a4000-7f0a588a2000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a588a2000-7f0a588a5000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a588a5000-7f0a589a3000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a589a3000-7f0a589a4000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a589a4000-7f0a58ad7000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a58ad7000-7f0a58c6d000 r-xs 02fb3000 08:22 28821744                   /opt/java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/rt.jar
7f0a58c6d000-7f0a58cb7000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a58cb7000-7f0a58cb8000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a58cb8000-7f0a58ec0000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a58ec0000-7f0a58ec1000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a58ec1000-7f0a58fc1000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a58fc1000-7f0a58fc2000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a58fc2000-7f0a6897c000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a6897c000-7f0a68b60000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a68b60000-7f0a69356000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a69356000-7f0a6a30d000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a6a30d000-7f0a6a3a2000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a6a3a2000-7f0a6ab98000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a6ab98000-7f0a6bb4f000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a6bb4f000-7f0a6bb6c000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a6bb6c000-7f0a6bd4f000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a6bd4f000-7f0a763b0000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0a763b0000-7f0b74ef0000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0b74ef0000-7f0d6bd50000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0d6bd50000-7f0d6f648000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0d6f648000-7f0dabd50000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0dabd50000-7f0dabd51000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0dabd51000-7f0dabe51000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0dabe51000-7f0dabe52000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0dabe52000-7f0dabf52000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0dabf52000-7f0dabf53000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0dabf53000-7f0dac053000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0dac053000-7f0dac054000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0dac054000-7f0dac154000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0dac154000-7f0dac155000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0dac155000-7f0dac255000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0dac255000-7f0dac256000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0dac256000-7f0dac356000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0dac356000-7f0dac357000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0dac357000-7f0dac457000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0dac457000-7f0dac458000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0dac458000-7f0dac564000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0dac564000-7f0dac618000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0dac618000-7f0dac8e8000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0dac8e8000-7f0daf618000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0daf618000-7f0daf626000 r-xp 00000000 08:22 28893231                   /opt/java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
7f0daf626000-7f0daf728000 ---p 0000e000 08:22 28893231                   /opt/java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
7f0daf728000-7f0daf72b000 rwxp 00010000 08:22 28893231                   /opt/java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so
7f0daf72b000-7f0daf72c000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0daf72c000-7f0daf733000 r-xp 00000000 08:22 28893233                   /opt/java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads/libhpi.so
7f0daf733000-7f0daf834000 ---p 00007000 08:22 28893233                   /opt/java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads/libhpi.so
7f0daf834000-7f0daf836000 rwxp 00008000 08:22 28893233                   /opt/java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/amd64/native_threads/libhpi.so
7f0daf836000-7f0daf837000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0daf837000-7f0daf84c000 r-xp 00000000 08:22 9781321                    /lib64/libnsl-2.11.2.so
7f0daf84c000-7f0dafa4b000 ---p 00015000 08:22 9781321                    /lib64/libnsl-2.11.2.so
7f0dafa4b000-7f0dafa4c000 r-xp 00014000 08:22 9781321                    /lib64/libnsl-2.11.2.so
7f0dafa4c000-7f0dafa4d000 rwxp 00015000 08:22 9781321                    /lib64/libnsl-2.11.2.so
7f0dafa4d000-7f0dafa4f000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0dafa4f000-7f0dafa78000 r-xp 00000000 08:22 28893244                   /opt/java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
7f0dafa78000-7f0dafb77000 ---p 00029000 08:22 28893244                   /opt/java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
7f0dafb77000-7f0dafb7e000 rwxp 00028000 08:22 28893244                   /opt/java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so
7f0dafb7e000-7f0dafb8b000 r-xp 00000000 08:22 28893226                   /opt/java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
7f0dafb8b000-7f0dafc8a000 ---p 0000d000 08:22 28893226                   /opt/java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
7f0dafc8a000-7f0dafc8d000 rwxp 0000c000 08:22 28893226                   /opt/java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so
7f0dafc8d000-7f0dafc95000 r-xp 00000000 08:22 9781495                    /lib64/librt-2.11.2.so
7f0dafc95000-7f0dafe94000 ---p 00008000 08:22 9781495                    /lib64/librt-2.11.2.so
7f0dafe94000-7f0dafe95000 r-xp 00007000 08:22 9781495                    /lib64/librt-2.11.2.so
7f0dafe95000-7f0dafe96000 rwxp 00008000 08:22 9781495                    /lib64/librt-2.11.2.so
7f0dafe96000-7f0dafe99000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0dafe99000-7f0daff97000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0daff97000-7f0daffed000 r-xp 00000000 08:22 9781318                    /lib64/libm-2.11.2.so
7f0daffed000-7f0db01ec000 ---p 00056000 08:22 9781318                    /lib64/libm-2.11.2.so
7f0db01ec000-7f0db01ed000 r-xp 00055000 08:22 9781318                    /lib64/libm-2.11.2.so
7f0db01ed000-7f0db01ee000 rwxp 00056000 08:22 9781318                    /lib64/libm-2.11.2.so
7f0db01ee000-7f0db094c000 r-xp 00000000 08:22 28893251                   /opt/java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
7f0db094c000-7f0db0a4b000 ---p 0075e000 08:22 28893251                   /opt/java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
7f0db0a4b000-7f0db0bc3000 rwxp 0075d000 08:22 28893251                   /opt/java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
7f0db0bc3000-7f0db0c01000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0db0c01000-7f0db0d58000 r-xp 00000000 08:22 9781310                    /lib64/libc-2.11.2.so
7f0db0d58000-7f0db0f57000 ---p 00157000 08:22 9781310                    /lib64/libc-2.11.2.so
7f0db0f57000-7f0db0f5b000 r-xp 00156000 08:22 9781310                    /lib64/libc-2.11.2.so
7f0db0f5b000-7f0db0f5c000 rwxp 0015a000 08:22 9781310                    /lib64/libc-2.11.2.so
7f0db0f5c000-7f0db0f61000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0db0f61000-7f0db0f63000 r-xp 00000000 08:22 9781316                    /lib64/libdl-2.11.2.so
7f0db0f63000-7f0db1163000 ---p 00002000 08:22 9781316                    /lib64/libdl-2.11.2.so
7f0db1163000-7f0db1164000 r-xp 00002000 08:22 9781316                    /lib64/libdl-2.11.2.so
7f0db1164000-7f0db1165000 rwxp 00003000 08:22 9781316                    /lib64/libdl-2.11.2.so
7f0db1165000-7f0db117c000 r-xp 00000000 08:22 9781346                    /lib64/libpthread-2.11.2.so
7f0db117c000-7f0db137c000 ---p 00017000 08:22 9781346                    /lib64/libpthread-2.11.2.so
7f0db137c000-7f0db137d000 r-xp 00017000 08:22 9781346                    /lib64/libpthread-2.11.2.so
7f0db137d000-7f0db137e000 rwxp 00018000 08:22 9781346                    /lib64/libpthread-2.11.2.so
7f0db137e000-7f0db1382000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0db1382000-7f0db13a1000 r-xp 00000000 08:22 14204938                   /lib64/ld-2.11.2.so
7f0db13a1000-7f0db13a2000 r-xs 00002000 08:22 22274903                   /home/frank/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.0.6/maven-reporting-api-2.0.6.jar
7f0db13a2000-7f0db13a4000 r-xs 00008000 08:22 25102115                   /home/frank/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/mojo/exec-maven-plugin/1.2.1/exec-maven-plugin-1.2.1.jar
7f0db13a4000-7f0db13a7000 r-xs 00019000 08:22 28287289                   /opt/maven/3.0.2/lib/aether-util-1.9.jar
7f0db13a7000-7f0db144f000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0db144f000-7f0db1456000 r-xp 00000000 08:22 28893216                   /opt/java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
7f0db1456000-7f0db1557000 ---p 00007000 08:22 28893216                   /opt/java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
7f0db1557000-7f0db1559000 rwxp 00008000 08:22 28893216                   /opt/java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
7f0db1559000-7f0db155a000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0db155a000-7f0db155b000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0db155b000-7f0db1567000 r-xs 0007a000 08:22 28287271                   /opt/maven/3.0.2/lib/maven-core-3.0.2.jar
7f0db1567000-7f0db156b000 r-xs 00033000 08:22 28287270                   /opt/maven/3.0.2/lib/plexus-utils-2.0.4.jar
7f0db156b000-7f0db156d000 r-xs 0000a000 08:22 28287266                   /opt/maven/3.0.2/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar
7f0db156d000-7f0db1574000 r-xs 00000000 08:22 23127397                   /usr/lib64/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
7f0db1574000-7f0db1595000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0db1595000-7f0db159d000 rwxs 00000000 08:22 4194917                    /tmp/hsperfdata_frank/11730
7f0db159d000-7f0db159e000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0db159e000-7f0db159f000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0db159f000-7f0db15a0000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f0db15a0000-7f0db15a1000 r-xp 0001e000 08:22 14204938                   /lib64/ld-2.11.2.so
7f0db15a1000-7f0db15a2000 rwxp 0001f000 08:22 14204938                   /lib64/ld-2.11.2.so
7f0db15a2000-7f0db15a3000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fff938f8000-7fff93919000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff939af000-7fff939b0000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:MaxPermSize=1g -Xms4g -Xmx12g -Dclassworlds.conf=/opt/maven/latest/bin/m2.conf -Dmaven.home=/opt/maven/latest 
java_command: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.cxw.Cxw -Dcxv.verbose=false -Dexec.args=-inputFileOrDirectory /idx1/Xc1/en0000 -indexDirectory /idx2/index 
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/6.0
JRE_HOME=/usr/lib64/jvm/jre
PATH=/opt/java/6.0/bin/:/opt/java/7.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games:/opt/kde3/bin:/usr/lib/mit/bin:/usr/lib/mit/sbin:/usr/NX/bin:/usr/lib/qt3/bin:/home/frank/.rvm/bin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/amd64/server:/opt/java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/amd64:/opt/java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/../lib/amd64
SHELL=/bin/bash
HOSTTYPE=x86_64
OSTYPE=linux
MACHTYPE=x86_64-suse-linux

Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0x6bddc0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0x6bddc0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0x594f90], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGPIPE: [libjvm.so+0x594f90], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0x594f90], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0x594f90], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000000
SIGUSR2: [libjvm.so+0x597750], sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGHUP: [libjvm.so+0x5974a0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGINT: [libjvm.so+0x5974a0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGTERM: [libjvm.so+0x5974a0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004
SIGQUIT: [libjvm.so+0x5974a0], sa_mask[0]=0x7ffbfeff, sa_flags=0x10000004


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:openSUSE 11.3 (x86_64)
VERSION = 11.3

uname:Linux 2.6.34.10-0.4-desktop #1 SMP PREEMPT 2011-10-19 22:16:41 +0200 x86_64
libc:glibc 2.11.2 NPTL 2.11.2 
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE infinity, NPROC 193169, NOFILE 8192, AS 21596640k
load average:0.24 0.21 0.22

CPU:total 8 (8 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 26 stepping 4, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, ht

Memory: 4k page, physical 24738624k(20253008k free), swap 2257096k(2257096k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (14.2-b01) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.6.0_16-b01), built on Jul 31 2009 05:52:33 by "java_re" with gcc 3.2.2 (SuSE Linux)

time: Tue Jan 10 15:42:56 2012
elapsed time: 6 seconds
```

Comment: Ugh. I didn't think Java was meant to segfault.

Comment: I would give a try by removing this entry -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepG

Comment: @thinksteep already done that. the same problem!!!

Comment: Is there any JNI code involved in the whole process? Are you doing this against a local disk? If so, did you check for disk errors?

Comment: does it still happen with -Xint ?

Comment: your JAVA_HOME is /opt/java/6.0 and your LD_LIBRARY_PATH starts with /opt/java/jdk1.6.0_16/... - if those aren't the same directory, that's bad news.

Comment: @araqnid 6.0 is just a symlink to the jdk1.6.0_16.

Comment: @mindas no there is no JNI code.

Comment: @araqnid yes, the same happens even after adding "-Xint".

Comment: Upgrade your JDK. The crash is in HotSpot code, and likely a bug resolved in later release. Edit: See you tested on 6 & 7 latest. Perhaps increase the stack size or stack shadow size...

Comment: I recommend communicating with the lucene user mailing list.

Comment: Why are you running JRE 6.0_16-b01 if you know that the version 6.0_27 is out, and all they do in those updates is fixing Bugs? Have you tried updating your environment?

Comment: @SHiRKiT as I said in the question, I tested both in the latest 6.0 and 7.0. The same thing.

Comment: Have you tried JDK 6.0_u29? The lastest uptadted JDK 6? Two out of three softwares I made didn't work on the JDK 7 without crashing about 2-3 months ago. I don't trust JDK 7 yet.

Comment: @SHiRKiT yes, I tried both u29 and the latest one u30. The same problem. It seems something related to HW. I tried even IBM J9, it also crashed!

Comment: Have you run hardware diagnostics (i.e., memory tests) on the machine? If it crashes all those different JVMs with different arguments, the only common factor is the enormous heap. Maybe a bad memory cell.

Comment: Could you try an alternative VM, not from Sun? If it also crashes, the problem stays, but if not, then you confirmed it's a bug. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines

Comment: @FabioCeconello yes, as I said before, I tried Sun, IBM J9, and Oracle Jrockit. The process crashes on all of them.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill yes, I run memory-test which did not detect any problems.

Comment: Well, it's (1) not a JVM bug, (2) not a hardware problem, (3) not a Java coding problem (that would be impossible) and (4) not native code. So... have you tried inverting the tachyon emitters? :)

Comment: I agree, there's not much left. It would be highly improbable that JVMs from different companies could have exactly the same bug. Were all the tests made in the same machine? Is the behavior reproducible in another one?

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill its not a java coding problem, because it crashes if I attempt to build (with ant) any library, e.g. tried to compile lucene, but the ant process failed with the same error.

Comment: So *any* JVM crashes *whatever* you do, then? It's got to be a hardware problem.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill It seems something related to hardware definitely. The only thing that was changed is the RAM. So I ran the memtest and no errors: http://bit.ly/xs8C5V. So this is driving me nuts!

Comment: @frankmoss how long did you run memtest for? I've seen at least one machine that could complete several passes before any errors were reported.

Comment: @awoodlang 8 hours. There have been several passes there too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was indeed hardware. After having looked at the BIOS settings, there was an alternative "System memory multiplier" which was set to 12. I changed this setting to "Auto", the crash does not happen any more. So, I thought it might help for others having similar issues.

Another point. Why only java processes were crashing still remains a mystery. Other processes were running fine. I guess, if there was a serious error with the memory, the other processes should not run either.

Anyway, its working now and thanks everybody for comments.

Answer (score 0):

I faces with a similar problem [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257346/java-kill-suddenly)

and solve it changing jre and  memory limit parameters.

Comment: what do you mean with "memory limit"?